# How to create an .scl file for MPLABX?

Tags: microcontroller, simulation, microchip, mplabx, mplab

I am using MPLABX simulator to simulate some code. I want to create a signal for an external pin of the MCU using the stimulus. To do this I need to attach an `.scl` file with the code. I do have the code as a text file.

How do I convert this text file into a .scl file ?

Comment: Can you show us the text 'code'?

Comment: @BruceAbbott it is the code saved in a text file. Cant really show it cause it is not mine.

Comment: Then we can't tell you how to convert it! Can you at least show a snippet of it so we can see the format?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you only need to change the extension from a .txt to a .scl, by saving it as such.

Comment: Why would you need a text editor to rename a file?

Comment: Can a text editor not be used to rename a text file, then? Because, the OP stated that their file was in text form, it made logical sense to propose that they use a text editor to perform the task. I don't see why my answer is being penalised, if the essence of it is not incorrect.

Comment: It feels like an extra step with a detour, as most operating systems can be used to rename or duplicate a file with a new name, via some sort of graphical file manager or command line terminal. So while renaming the file might be the correct answer, the explained method how to rename a file is just cumbersome - most people in Windows would just press F2 to rename a file. You can edit your answer to remove the specific way of renaming the file if you want.

Comment: An extra step or cumbersome doesn't negate the fact that the correct answer was provided. To penalise someone for providing a method that is apparently cumbersome (for some) is akin to stating that only certain methods will be tolerated. From my understanding, this site is built on people providing different methods to solving a problem, just like Maths and engineering are based on different methods to obtaining a solution. Also, I've been using Windows for years and I never knew that pressing F2 would initiate the process renaming a file. Would be nice to know what % of people know this.

Comment: I guess you are right. I guess we should assume people know how to rename files in their operating system one way or another and choose the best. But we don't even know if this was on Windows, Linux, or MacOS. I guess we will never get an answer to that as  question was abandonded almost 3 years ago. I did remove my downvote now.

Comment: Thank you for your acknowledgement and for removing the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:scl), an SCL file is just a text file with the specific file name extension, similarly to any source file, be it C or VHDL.

You can use any tool that can rename files, for example Window's file explorer, or the command line.